# How to embed HTML content in BI report for bursting?

Tags: html, sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I want to send HTML Email from BI publisher, but the HTML is not getting recognized by the SQL query and it is trying to interpret it further.

How can I make use of that HTML as a literal with dynamic values returned by the query?

Comment: Title and question are different... 'Embedding HTML in a BI report for bursting' and 'Sending HTML Email from BI Publisher' are not the same and I'm quite sure the latter is impossible.

Comment: @Peter Paff hope you are aware of both the termniologies and yes its possible to send email from BIPublisher and the format could be text or html.

Comment: Maybe from OBIEE, but certainly not from BI Publisher. The problem isnt terminology, sending a HTML email is different from embedding HTML in a BI report. There is also nothing relating to bursting in your question or answer besides the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `htf.escape_sc()` function which will take care of escaping HTML. It will use HTML entities internally. e.g. `<` will get converted into `&lt;`